# How do I not have R overwrite the other values

Tags: r, loops, return

Here's my function

```
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332) {
  files_list <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)
  nobs <- numeric()
  for (i in id) {
    nob <- sum(complete.cases(read.csv(files_list[i])))

  }
  nobs <- c(nobs, nob)
  dat <- return(data.frame(id, nobs))
} 

complete(specdata, 1)
complete(specdata, c(2, 4, 8, 10, 12))
```

This returns

```
> complete(specdata, 1)
  id nobs
1  1  117
> complete(specdata, c(2, 4, 8, 10, 12))
  id nobs
1  2   96
2  4   96
3  8   96
4 10   96
5 12   96
```

While I get the correct single values, 
the different ids should have different ending values, 
at the moment, all the values are overwritten by the final value.

How do get it to not do that?

Comment: put "nobs <- c(nobs, nob)" inside the for loop?

Comment: @StupidWolf. THANK YOU. It worked, but at the same time, I found another way to solve the problem.

Comment: This code is part of the first programming assignment for the Johns Hopkins R Programming course on Coursera. Per the *Coursera Honor Code*, students are not allowed to post complete versions of programming assignments to the internet, even if they contain errors. Please delete this question to comply with the Honor Code.

Comment: Hey Len, 
My deepest apologies for posting this. But I am currently unable to delete this post. When trying to delete this post, it replies with:
"You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it" and also gives this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys, 
I ended up finding out an alternative method.

```
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332){
  files_list <- list.files(directory, full.names = T) # creates a list of files.
  dat <- data.frame() #creates an empty data frame
  nobs <- numeric()
  for (i in id) {
    dat <- read.csv(files_list[i])    
    nobs <- c(nobs, sum(complete.cases(dat)))
  }  
  return(data.frame(id, nobs))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion from @StupidWolf should solve your problem, however here is another way :

```
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332) {
   files_list <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)[id]
   data.frame(id, nobs = sapply(files_list, function(x) nrow(na.omit(read.csv(x)))))
}
```

Comment: Error in data.frame(id, nobs = sapply(files_list, function(x) nrow(na.omit(read.csv(x))))) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 5, 332

Comment: @strki sorry...I had a small mistake. You need to subset `files_list` based on `id`. I have corrected the answer.

Comment: Hey, I've upvoted, but my votes are not considered public at this moment